# How to get all attributes list with details that assigned to Used in product Listing-> Yes in magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes

**How to get all attributes list with details that assigned to  Used in product Listing-> Yes in custom.phtml file in Magento2**

Answer (score 2):

Using below code you will get all Attributes which has the property "Used" in product Listing-> Yes.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$attributes = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Config')->getAttributesUsedInListing();

foreach($attributes as $attribute){
   print_r($attribute);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

- Crate Block file in your module and add below code. please update your module namespace & name in below code.

  ```
  namespace Mymodule\ProductCollection\Block;
  class ProductCollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
  {    
      protected $_productCollectionFactory;    
      public function __construct(
          \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
          \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory                             $productCollectionFactory,        
          array $data = []
      )
      {    
          $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
          parent::__construct($context, $data);
      }

      public function getProductCollection()
      {
          $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
          $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
          $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products
          return $collection;
      }
  }
  ```
- Show product collection in PHTML file

> ```
> $productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
>
> foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
>     print_r($product->getData());
> }
> ```